# How to use mouseenter with element ui

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events, element-ui

I am trying to collapse vertical menus upon mouseenter events but it is not working properly.

Any thought?

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        isCollapse: true
      };
    },
    methods: {
      switchCollapse(){
        this.isCollapse = !this.isCollapse;
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.el-menu-vertical-demo:not(.el-menu--collapse) {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-menu default-active="2" class="el-menu-vertical-demo" @mouseenter.native="switchCollapse" :collapse="isCollapse">
  <el-submenu index="1">
    <template slot="title">
      <i class="el-icon-location"></i>
      <span slot="title">Navigator One</span>
    </template>
    <el-menu-item-group>
      <span slot="title">Group One</span>
      <el-menu-item index="1-1">item one</el-menu-item>
      <el-menu-item index="1-2">item two</el-menu-item>
    </el-menu-item-group>
    <el-menu-item-group title="Group Two">
      <el-menu-item index="1-3">item three</el-menu-item>
    </el-menu-item-group>
    <el-submenu index="1-4">
      <span slot="title">item four</span>
      <el-menu-item index="1-4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
    </el-submenu>
  </el-submenu>
  <el-menu-item index="2">
    <i class="el-icon-menu"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Two</span>
  </el-menu-item>
  <el-menu-item index="3" disabled>
    <i class="el-icon-document"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Three</span>
  </el-menu-item>
  <el-menu-item index="4">
    <i class="el-icon-setting"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Four</span>
  </el-menu-item>
</el-menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 2 differents mouse events : `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        isCollapse: true
      };
    },
    methods: {
      removeCollapse(){
        this.isCollapse = false;
      },
      collapse(){
        this.isCollapse = true;
      },
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.2/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.el-menu-vertical-demo:not(.el-menu--collapse) {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.9.2/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<el-menu default-active="2" class="el-menu-vertical-demo" @mouseenter.native="removeCollapse"
@mouseleave.native="collapse" 
:collapse="isCollapse">
  <el-submenu index="1">
    <template slot="title">
      <i class="el-icon-location"></i>
      <span slot="title">Navigator One</span>
    </template>
    <el-menu-item-group>
      <span slot="title">Group One</span>
      <el-menu-item index="1-1">item one</el-menu-item>
      <el-menu-item index="1-2">item two</el-menu-item>
    </el-menu-item-group>
    <el-menu-item-group title="Group Two">
      <el-menu-item index="1-3">item three</el-menu-item>
    </el-menu-item-group>
    <el-submenu index="1-4">
      <span slot="title">item four</span>
      <el-menu-item index="1-4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
    </el-submenu>
  </el-submenu>
  <el-menu-item index="2">
    <i class="el-icon-menu"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Two</span>
  </el-menu-item>
  <el-menu-item index="3" disabled>
    <i class="el-icon-document"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Three</span>
  </el-menu-item>
  <el-menu-item index="4">
    <i class="el-icon-setting"></i>
    <span slot="title">Navigator Four</span>
  </el-menu-item>
</el-menu>
</div>
```